# How can I see what is on the Desktop Heap

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have an application that is using about 100k more of the Desktop Heap in this version then it did last version.  Is there a way I can see what is on the Desktop Heap and how big the individual objects are?  Using [Dheapmon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5CFC9B74-97AA-4510-B4B9-B2DC98C8ED8B&displaylang=en) I was able to see what percentage of the heap I was using, but I want more details.

Answer (score 1):

Dheapmon is the only tool I know of for looking directly at the desktop heap, but have you tried looking at your application with a tool like [Winspector](http://www.windows-spy.com/) to look for glaring differences between the two versions (say, some type of control in your application now contains far more windows)?  Any chance the application has switched to a newer version of IE?  I seem to remember IE7 being much more desktop heap-intensive than IE6...

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from a comment on a blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx)

> Let me
> give a little background on how
> desktop heap allocations are made. The
> desktop heaps are in kernel mode
> virtual address space, so individual
> desktop heap allocations have to be
> made by a component running in kernel
> mode. In particular, win32k.sys is the
> only kernel mode component that makes
> desktop heap allocations. win32k.sys
> in the kernel mode side of Win32, and
> it includes both the window manager
> (USER) and GDI. It is the window
> manager piece of win32k.sys that uses
> desktop heap. The functionality of the
> window manager is exposed to processes
> running in user mode through
> user32.dll. It is user32.dll that
> exports user mode callable functions
> that are implemented in win32k.sys. So
> if a process does not load user32.dll,
> it will not use desktop heap.
>
> Regarding your question about **setting
> a breakpoint** that will catch desktop
> heap allocations... yes, there is such
> a function - **win32k!DesktopAlloc**.
> However, this is a kernel mode
> function, and to set a breakpoint on
> it will require that you use a **kernel
> debugger.**

That sounds all scary complicated to me who has never ventured away from user-mode in Windows.

When I had a similar problem I just put break points all over the startup portion of our application. At each break I would watch the level of allocated handles and what dhelpmon told me. Doing a sort of binary search I started to narrow down where the allocations were happening.

Answer (score -2):

You can walk the heap using the Win32 API call [HeapWalk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366710(VS.85).aspx).  You can call [GetProcessHeap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366571(VS.85).aspx) to get all the heaps available to the process if you need to walk more than just the default heap.

Comment: I'm not so sure the "desktop" heap is available to just any process. I think dheapmon does some kernal-mode and/or debugger-like thing to get the info it reports.